# php code stops running

Tags: php, mysql

I was using this script from last couple of years but suddenly it giving error of invaild users or password, i didn't change anything in code and server, all things are there db/users etc. any one got any idea? following is the code

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

            $username = $_POST['emailnic'];
            $username = $_POST['password'];


            $INic=substr($username,0,5)."-".substr($username,5,7)."-".substr($username,12,1);
            include('con.php');
            $Query = mysql_query("SELECT NicNo,Email,Password,AcStatus,Actype FROM person WHERE NicNo='$INic' && Password='$password' || Email='$username' && Password='$password' ") or die(mysql_error());    


        $show=mysql_num_rows($Query);
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($Query);
        mysql_close($dbhandle); 
        if( $show >=1 )
         {


             $s=$result['AcStatus'];
             $t=$result['Actype'];
             $_SESSION['user_ACType']=$result['Actype'];
             $_SESSION['user_NIC']=$result['NicNo'];

            if($s==1 and $t==3)
            {

                header( 'Location: ../index_login.php' ) ;
            }
            else if($s==1 && $t==2)
            {

                header( 'Location: ../admin2.php' ) ;
            }
            else if($s==1 && $t==1)
            {

                header( "Location:../Admin.php" ) ;
            }
            else if($s==0 && $t==0)
            {
                  $_SESSION['error'] = "Your Account Avtivated After Varification!!!";


                header( "Location:../login.php" ) ;

            }

        }
        else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid User Name or Password!!!";

                header( "Location:../login.php" ) ;

            }

?>
```

thanks
Kami

Comment: Take a look at [ask].

Comment: You are vulernable to sql injection kindly use mysqli or pdo..

Comment: Something must have changed if it worked for years. Do you receive any errors? I'd start by looking at your query, the conditions there are not well formatted.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Run a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` code inside a new php page, in order to find out the version.

Comment: If you're just going to ask a question and leave, without answering our comments, people will tire of waiting for a response from you and leave the question, lowering the chance of you getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Fromwhereyouaregettigvalueof$password.checkthis=>$username = $_POST['emailnic'];
            $username = $_POST['password'];

Comment: from another file which is on root folder just passing these values

Comment: one more thing all the things are working fine on local server xamp in my pc